# Multiplication of all numbers in a cell by a specific number

Tags: excel, csv, google-sheets

I have a small problem. I would like to multiply all the numbers in a cell from a new line by 1.8, but unfortunately I am getting gently lost. I tried combining with array and split but in the end I was unsuccessful.

[image]

Comment: Why would anybody put multiple values inside one cell???

Comment: Don't ask me...  I got it and I'm suffering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Google sheets try the following:

```
=BYROW(B111:B114, 
   LAMBDA(y, 
     INDEX(IFERROR(JOIN(CHAR(10),(SPLIT(y,CHAR(10))*2))))))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With ms365, try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MAP(A1:A3,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,TEXTSPLIT(x,CHAR(10))*1,8)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

[image]

Using a cell defined as a name.

You can even use names defined on one sheet in a different sheet - so those constants can be kept in one place and be updated easily.

Names can be used across workbooks but that can get challenging :)